# Load custom css after 3rd party plugin css in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm searching for the "right way" to add a custom.css file after the 3rd party plugin has loaded theirs. I know how to register and enqueue my css files in functions.php. Can I somehow add a dependency for the 3rd party plugin stylesheets?
For example I want to load a custom.css file afer the plugin woocomerce has loaded. I want this without editing the plugin. Can this be done in functions.php?

Comment: You can dequeue and enqueue the woocommerce stylesheets in your functions.php file and/or set a higher priority to your custom styles when enqueueing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct way to do this would be to just utilize woocommerce's general stylesheet as a dependency using [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_woocommerce_styles' );
function my_woocommerce_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-wc-style', 'path/to/my-styles.css', array( 'woocommerce-general' ), '1.0' );
}
```

Woocommerce has multiple stylesheets registered under different handles - but you're most likely looking for `woocommerce-general`.

Using it as a dependency like that will only load it if `woocommerce-general` has been loaded for that particular request, and it will load it afterwards. You may need to adjust the priority of the `add_action` depending on exactly how/where you're doing this. You mentioned `functions.php` so it shouldn't be necessary, but you if you need to, just pass another priority to it, for example:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_woocommerce_styles', 15 );
```

Comment: @ShawnHayes - you're absolutely correct! I've updated the snippet. Thanks for pointing that out